# Preventing visible seams UV edges when baking normals from high-poly?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

As you can see below, I am getting some hard edges along my UV seams when baking from high-poly to low-poly. I've tried baking in Substance Painter as well as in Blender with many different settings, and I get the exact same issue. If I bake to a 4k map the seams are less noticeable, but still definitely there. I just can't seem to find a rock-solid solution to fixing this issue. Now i'm just wondering if this is just something that we have to deal with while baking.

Details: Low poly mesh has no hard edges and is smooth shaded with no autosmooth. I've looked it over multiple times and can confirm that it is the ideal mesh for baking. It and the high poly mesh match up very well and I have to do very little finagling with ray distance.

What am I overlooking?

Edit: I've uploaded a .blend file with the high and low poly rocks here: https://ufile.io/gqn8bhbo

Here's a baked 1k normal map(top) and a 512x512 map (bottom):
[image: Edges]

[image]

The problem gets much worse with lower res textures.

Comment: Read Tangent Basis section of this guide: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Texture_Baking

Comment: Could you please share your file with high poly and low poly meshes?

Comment: Arthur, thank you for the answer! This has been bugging me for months and it's nice to know i'm not just crazy.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think it's hard to fake smooth angles with normal maps, so maybe you should bevel a bit these angle?